# Resolving validation dynamically for entity on the basis of data - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am facing a challenge here not able to figure out the right way to do it. Please give me a correct approach on how I can achieve this.

Given entity

```
Class Product 
{
   private $id;
   private $name;
   private $files;
   private $attributes;
   private $category;
}
```

Now we all know I can just create validation file under validation/Product.yml and Symfony takes care of the validation with appropriate config.

Now the challenge I am facing is how can I resolve dynamic validation rules on the basis of the category of product?
Suppose if I have 5 categories namely category1, category2, category3, category4 and category5.

I need to validate `$files` and `$attributes` properties on the basis of the category selected.
Given there can be any number of categories.

I have read about validation groups but since there can be any number of categories, group feature doesn't seem feasible here.

Comment: Do you think of writing your own contraint validator for this specific problem? [Constraint Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: @Violence Well yes, but still I think my problem is more advanced I have 50+ categories in the system which have their own set of rules which files and attributes are allowed. I am thinking of implementing a strategy pattern.

Comment: strategy pattern seems to be a good approach. I think the symfony validation is not able to deal with your problem directly. Show some code if you have problems with your ideas. Greets Violence :)